# Why is Rails not writing to development.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Suddenly my Rails 4.2 app is writing nothing to development.log.

Absolutely nothing!

I have tried checking the correct environment is being used, restarting the server, checking for gems that might interact with logger, checking permissions, `logger.flush`, and `rake log:clean`.

The log file is now completely empty, and nothing is being written.

Running `rails s` gives:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-03-14 18:49:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-14 18:49:57] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
[2015-03-14 18:49:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3963 port=3000
```

There are quite a few similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none provide an answer that has worked in my case.

I have no idea what would cause this or how to systematically debug.

What steps should I take?

Comment: what do you see when you do `rails s`?

Comment: added `rails s` output to questions

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, after much going round in circles, I finally found the culprit.

The `rails_12factor` is apparently overwriting config.logger.

See: https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/blob/master/lib/rails_stdout_logging/rails3.rb#L7

I removed this gem from the development environment (I really only need it in the deployed environment) and everything is now working.

To put a gem in production only, it needs to be in a gem environment group like this:

```
# This is override development.log output and should only go in production.
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Thanks @maxd for helping to get me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem can be caused by the following things:

1. You set to high log level. Check your `application.rb` and `environments\*.rb` files:

   ```
   # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
   config.log_level = :error
   ```
2. You set custom logging. Check your `application.rb`, `environments/*.rb` and all files in `initializers/*.rb`:

   ```
   # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
   config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)
   ```

These two steps should help you to investigate problem and fix it.

Comment: thanks @maxd, my `development.rb` file contains `config.log_level = :debug`.  I have searched all files for `config.logger` and the only place this occurs in my app is `production.rb`, where it is commented out. I tried adding `config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)` to `development.rb` just to see what happens, and I get `NameError: uninitialized constant SyslogLogger`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

restart server

Answer (score 0):

If in AWS (or similar) you have to make sure that your log directory has write access.